# Populating a column with true/false if there's a row that matches two conditions in another dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe, df1, with locations and species seen at that location. It looks like this:

```
site     species
A        rainbow
A        rainbow
A        tessellated
B        rainbow
B        greenside
B        fantail
B        fantail
```

I've created a new dataframe, df2, using `unique(df1$site)` so that there's one row for each location. I'd like to create four columns, one for each species, populated with TRUE or FALSE depending on whether there's a row for that location that includes that species. It would look like this:

```
site     rainbow     tessellated     greenside     fantail
A        TRUE        TRUE            FALSE         FALSE
B        TRUE        FALSE           TRUE          TRUE
```

I'm sure there's a simple way to do this but I'm just not landing on anything. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Base R:

```
as.data.frame.matrix(table(df)>0)
  fantail greenside rainbow tessellated
A   FALSE     FALSE    TRUE        TRUE
B    TRUE      TRUE    TRUE       FALSE
```

---

```
tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from = species, 
                       values_from = species,
                       values_fn = ~length(.x) > 0, 
                       values_fill = FALSE)
# A tibble: 2 × 5
  site  rainbow tessellated greenside fantail
  <chr> <lgl>   <lgl>       <lgl>     <lgl>  
1 A     TRUE    TRUE        FALSE     FALSE  
2 B     TRUE    FALSE       TRUE      TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you - `pivot_wider` is exactly the simple answer I was looking for! For any future people with the same question, I did have to add `id_cols = site` because my actual dataframe had more columns than just site and species.

Comment: Actually... I just realized that there are some false negatives in the output, i.e. locations marked FALSE for species when they should be TRUE.

Comment: @MollyCohn that is not possible. The function `length(x) > 0` works if at all we have a length>0. Try the first approach and see whether it is also false. the two should give identical results

Comment: The first approach does work, thank you! Not sure why, but they do give different results. The output of `table(df) > 0` looks much more accurate as far as I can tell.

Comment: @MollyCohn well i have never seen such problem it sounds improbable. but will take you at your. You might consider using `id_cols` within `pivot_longer`

Answer (score 0):

One option to do this, is using dplyr:

```
for(species in unique(df1$species)) {
  df2 <- df2 |> 
    left_join(df1|> filter(species == !!species) |> mutate(!!species := TRUE) |> select(site, !!species), by = "site")
}

df2 <- df2 |> distinct(site, .keep_all = TRUE)

df2[is.na(df2)] <- FALSE

df2

  site rainbow tessellated greenside fantail
1    A    TRUE        TRUE     FALSE   FALSE
2    B    TRUE       FALSE      TRUE    TRUE
```